# Can I connect a PlayStation 3's HDMI output to my monitor's DVI-D input?

Tags: ps3

I'm attempting to connect my PlayStation 3 to my computer monitor. The monitor has a DVI-D (dual link) input, so before distinguishing between the different DVI varieties, I bought a DVI-I (dual link) to HDMI converter that won't fit into the port on the monitor (not only that, there isn't enough physical space in the back of the monitor to fit that much stuff before it hits the bottom of it).

So I grabbed a DVI-D (single link) cable and got a female-to-female DVI-I coupler, and plugged the DVI-D cable into the monitor and the whole mess of converters. The end result was HDMI to DVI-D single link, but my monitor isn't receiving a signal on its digital channel.

(For clarity's sake: DVI-D DL input on Monitor, DVI-D SL cable, DVI-I DL female-to-female coupler, DVI-I DL to HDMI converter, HDMI output on PS3)

I don't know much about this stuff (obviously), but my educated guess is that the bandwidth of the PS3 is too high for the DVI-D Single Link cable, so nothing's getting through. Will replacing the single link cable with dual link resolve this? If not, is it possible at all?

I'm aware I won't get audio through the monitor. I have an RCA to 3.5mm converter for that.

Comment: Some may think this is off-topic. I'm inclined to agree, except that expertise regarding necessary connectors is probably more likely found here than a gaming-specific site. My vote is for this being an acceptable exception to the PC-only requirement. A monitor is certainly part of a PC, and only differs based on it's usage.

Comment: Ah, yes, my apologies. Fixed.

Comment: Could you include a picture of this strange assortment of cables and adapters between your _mysterious HDMI source_ and the monitor? I'm finding the text a bit hard to follow.

Comment: Turns out it's all irrelevant, I did some troubleshooting and realized the problem is actually the source, a Playstation 3 (see above comment thread). The impossible-to-explain list of converters output to my monitor just fine when connected to the HDMI output of my laptop.

I'm fairly sure at this point that the problem is that my monitor doesn't support HDCP, and therefore my PS3 is staying on the opposite side of the playground. This leaves the following options: An HDCP stripper (not available in the U.S. that I know of), or giving up and going with RCA to VGA. *sigh*

Comment: If you'd like, I can migrate this question to [gaming.se] for you. They might have more experience with hooking a PS3 up to a non-HDCP compliant monitor. Are you sure your machine doesn't support HDCP or might it just be that a step in the connector chain doesn't?

Comment: Yes, if you think I'd get help from Gaming then feel free to move this. I'm heading to Radioshack today to return something anyway, so I might as well try an asymmetric HDMI to DVI cable while I'm there. I just won't tell them if it works I'll probably return the 40-dollar one anyway and get one on Amazon for 90 cents... eheh. If that doesn't work, then I can't think what would. (Don't ask me why I didn't try that to begin with, it's a long story)

Comment: The cable didn't work, I'm about out of ideas for anything HD. I'm seeing other reports of the same thing working just fine, but I tried messing with all the settings and holding the power button on startup. I suppose my monitor is too old, I've had it for approximately five years and got it pretty cheap. Reviews on this guy http://www.amazon.com/Wii-PS3-VGA-HDTV-Cable-Nintendo/dp/B0015MISAG/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top claim it converts it outputs good quality via VGA, so I suppose that's the next thing to try.

Answer (score 1):

Most DVI to HDMI converters are one way. I haven't yet seen one that is two way, or HDMI to DVI. I did, however, find [this](http://www.thesource.ca/estore/product.aspx?language=en-CA&product=1518871&category=Video_Adapters&catalog=Online&tab=1#more) adapter that claims to be HDMI to DVI

Comment: It seems the reason that the converters are generally one-way is because of High-Bandwidth Digital Content Protection which requires the display device interacting with an HDMI source to be compliant with the protocol to function.

Comment: @KevinBarboro I forgot about that, but yes, you are correct

Comment: Au contrair, I have an HDMI to DVI adapter with which I connect my laptop to my external monitor regularly. Not sure if HDCP is one-way though.

Comment: @nhinkle I'd be curious to find out if it is or not.